# how to use ggplot2 scale_color_hue over a vector

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2

Hi I'm trying to color groups in my plot based on their HCL value. It doesn't work the way I do it, I want to know how I can refer to it so each group gets its color based on their HCL color values

Data (Total):

```
      ID       L          a           b       DE       heightmm  L1        C         h       SDL        SDa
1  ClearHelder 58.83333  -2.2566667   1.07000 58.88333 17.666667 58.83333  2.50000 154.58333 1.6015721 0.08386497
2  Donkerblauw 32.26000  -0.3266667 -20.00000 37.97333 18.666667 32.26000 20.00333 269.06667 1.8712830 0.10692677
3  Donkerbruin 28.94333   5.1400000  14.84333 32.93333 21.666667 28.94333 15.71333  70.90000 0.6978777 0.17000000
4   Donkergeel 63.95667  -7.4466667  64.16667 90.91333 14.333333 63.95667 64.60000  96.62000 0.7595613 0.63263997
5  Donkergroen 37.16667 -23.6800000  14.54667 46.50333 10.333333 37.16667 27.79333 148.44667 2.7307569 0.45639895
6 Donkeroranje 49.57000  27.5033333  44.02667 71.78667  9.666667 49.57000 51.92000  58.01333 0.6242596 1.34001244

  SDb        SDDE       SDheightmm  SDL1      SDC        SDh        hex
1 0.09165151 1.6015721  1.1547005   1.6015721 0.03605551 2.6510815 #1B9E77
2 0.28844410 1.4758500  1.5275252   1.8712830 0.28290163 0.3265476 #D95F02
3 0.58320951 0.5753550  0.5773503   0.6978777 0.60177515 0.3395585 #7570B3
4 2.22554113 1.6346967  1.5275252   0.7595613 2.24006696 0.5111751 #E7298A
5 0.67352308 1.7712801  1.1547005   2.7307569 0.73934656 0.7169612 #66A61E
6 0.88793769 0.8957864  0.5773503   0.6242596 1.07670795 1.3266625 #E6AB02
```

I've tried the following codes to make it work:

```
ggplot(data = Total, aes(x = reorder(ID, h), y = h)) + 
  geom_crossbar(ymax = Total$h + Total$SDh, ymin = Total$h - Total$SDh) + 
  coord_flip() +
  scale_color_hue(h = Total$h, c = Total$C, l = Total$L)

# Warning message:
# In if ((diff(h)%%360) < 1) { :
# the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

ggplot(data = Total, aes(x = reorder(ID, h), y = h)) + 
  geom_crossbar(ymax = Total$h + Total$SDh, ymin = Total$h - Total$SDh) + 
  coord_flip() +
  scale_color_hue(h = h, c = C, l = L)

# Error in diff(h) : object 'h' not found
```

I've added a column with hex color values. Using this code the plot does partially what I want.

```
ggplot(data=Total, aes(x=ID, y=h)) + geom_crossbar(ymax=Total$h+Total$SDh, ymin=Total$h-Total$SDh, color=Total$hex) + coord_flip()
```

If there is a way to convert the lab values or the HCL values to hex values, I can put them in that column and have the solution.

I've tried the following code, this generated what I want, however for some lab value combinations it gave NA's

```
ggplot(data=Total, aes(x=reorder(ID,h), y=h)) + geom_crossbar(ymax=Total$h+Total$SDh, ymin=Total$h-Total$SDh, fill=hex(LAB(Total$L, Total$a, Total$b, Total$ID)), color=hex(LAB(Total$L, Total$a, Total$b, Total$ID))) + coord_flip()
```

Next I tried to do the same with the hcl values and this generated hex values for all the records and worked.

```
ggplot(data=Total, aes(x=reorder(ID,h), y=h)) + geom_crossbar(ymax=Total$h+Total$SDh, ymin=Total$h-Total$SDh, fill=hcl(Total$h, Total$C, Total$L1), color=hcl(Total$h, Total$C, Total$L1)) + coord_flip()
```

side note:

The hex colors generated with hex(LAB(...)) come closer to the real colors than the hex colors generated with hcl(...)

hex(LAB(...)) generates sometimes NA's to overcome this I replaced the NA's with the hex colors generated by hcl(...)

Comment: Hi, your example is irreproducible due to missing variables (SDh).

Comment: Sorry, corrected the post with the full data frame

Comment: I think scale_color_hue is not the way to go, as you seem to want to have the colour in your graph match the decription in the ID (I'm Dutch). Is that a correct assumption?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't post an example image, but it's partially right. The descriptions are indeed the colors of the different records. The plot generates a floating bar plot, for each ID the range (in the form of a bar) in which the ID lies on that specific parameter (in the case of the example code the h value).
I would like the bars to match the color of the ID discription by using the LCH values to determine the color to use for each bar.

Comment: I've updated my post, I only need a way to compute hex values based on the lab or HCL values for each record.

Comment: Does this help: `Total$hex <- hcl(h=Total$h, c=Total$C, l=Total$L)`?

Comment: Thanks Stibu, see updated post. the hcl function generated hex values for all lab values. This worked. I don't know however why hex(LAB(...)) generated for some lab value combination an NA... still a mistery.
If someone know, be welcome to elaborate since it's not always the case that I have lab and lch values both